# Why doesn't menu get added?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qmainwindow

I'm clearly missing something here; why doesn't the File menu get added in this little example app?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.exitAction = QAction('Exit', self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Quit, triggered=self.close)
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT:

Ok, it looks like this is actually a unicode issue.
Here's another example app:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, division
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.dummyAction = QAction(self.tr('dummy'), self, triggered=self.dummy)
        self.gameMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu(self.tr('ddddummy'))
        print (self.tr('dummy'))
        self.gameMenu.addAction(self.dummyAction)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def dummy(self):
        pass

locale = QLocale.system().name()
qtTranslator = QTranslator()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if qtTranslator.load('qt_' + locale, ':/'):
    app.installTranslator(qtTranslator)
w = Window()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This app doesn't have 'File' or 'Quit' or 'Exit' -- but it *works* if I comment out the `from __future__` line, or surround the quoted strings like `self.tr(str('foo'))` instead of `self.tr('foo')`

EDIT 2:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        print self.tr('foo')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Window().show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This should print 'foo', but prints nothing.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me either on OSX. Not sure why yet. Seems really odd. But it does work fine on linux

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make it work? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance, your code seems perfectly normal, and it does function just as expected on windows or linux. The issue here is that on OSX, the operating system enforces a standard interface on the menu. Whereas on other operating systems the menu is nested right under your app, and your app owns it...on OSX, the operating system owns it. Hence it is shown in the global menu area.

That being said, OSX is filtering out some reserved keywords like "Quit" or "Exit". The reason for this is because the quit functionality is a standard that is automatically placed in your Application menu. When you run it as a basic python script, the menu will be called "Python". But if you bundle it into an app, it will be named accordingly for your bundled app.

This [link here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/mac-differences.html#limitations), while not an exact explanation, does mention the differences for a menu on OSX.

For a quick example of fixing your menu, see what happens when you do:

```
    self.exitAction = QAction('Kwit', self)
```

OSX will not filter out that one. But I suppose its better to follow the native standards which make all app experiences the same on the platform. You would definitely include the "Quit" menu action as you have it now, so that your app will be cross-platform if run on linux or windows and just expect that OSX will relocate it for you.

Comment: Good try, but it seems the problem I'm having is actually different - see edit.

Comment: Well it worked completely fine on ubuntu linux and didnt on osx... only worked after this issue was swapped out. I cant reproduce your unicode problem so I have no idea. Could be version specific to qt/pyside or the python interp you are using.

Comment: This worked for me, though I was having a second issue with the toolbar not changing when using the raise_() event. I had to click off my application then back on it to change the bar and see the 'kwit'.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this thread because I'm struggling with a similar issue.  Here's what I've found...

About your EDIT 2:
Your code will correctly print 'foo' if you substitute the line

```
Window().show()
```

for the lines

```
w = Window()
w.show()
```

as you had in your original code.  Apparently the return type on the constructor causes chaining to be an issue in python?

I was able to reproduce your EDIT 1 by commenting out the `from __future__` line.  Otherwise, the code below works as expected in OS X (Mountain Lion 10.8.3 with brewed python).  Specifically, the following code puts the "About" action under the "Python" application menu that OS X creates, and also creates a "Help" menu containing the "Website" action.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication,QMainWindow, QWidget, QAction

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.create_menus()
        self.create_main_frame()

    def create_menus(self):
        self.aboutAction = QAction('About', self, triggered=self.on_about)
        self.websiteAction = QAction('Website', self, triggered=self.on_website)
        self.help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Help')
        self.help_menu.addAction(self.aboutAction)
        self.help_menu.addAction(self.websiteAction)

    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    def on_website(self):
        pass

    def on_about(self):
        pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I should draw attention to an important point that this thread helped me discover.  I've seen a lot of advice for OS X that indicates you should create `menu_bar = QMenuBar()` independently of `QMainWindow` and then bind with `self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)` where `self` represents `QMainWindow`.  This, in fact, didn't work for me.  Instead, what did work, is grabbing the menu bar reference directly from the QMainWindow class itself.  For example, and like above, when adding a menu, use `self.help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('Help')` as above.